# Moving a private key without passphrase from a server to another causes request of passphrase by GPG

Tags: encryption, debian, rsa, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I generated a key pair using GPG by following command in Debian 8.

```
gpg --gen-key
```

I left the passphrase step of key generation empty and just hit the Enter key. After that, I exported private and public key using following commands.

```
gpg --export-secret-key -a "X" > private.key
gpg --export-key -a "X" > public.key
```

Then I tried to encrypt a folder using the private key. It was successful and without asking any passphrase the encrypted file was generated.
But When I transferred the public key to another computer with Ubuntu OS 14.04 and import it using following command, gpg requested passphrase. Even, by giving empty passphrase to gpg, it says that passphrase is incorrect.

```
gpg --import public.key
```

Furthermore, when I imported the private key in the second computer for encryption, it asks me passphrase again.
Does anyone have any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because there exist other keyring in second system before. Indeed, it is required to clear all keys before import

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to export and import keys. Just copy the key files located in ~/.ssh/ on your source machine to the other system.